# Compare angle with angle range

Tags: php, bearing

I have a problem finding a good way of finding out if the bearing is in between the range.

I have a variable called `$bearing`, and this needs to be compared with `$CompareAngel +-20 degrees`.
For example $CompareAngle can be 90 degrees, then the below code should be true with $bearing beeing values 70-110 degrees.

```
if($bearing >= $CompareAngle-20 && $bearing <= $CompareAngle+20)
```

This works fine as long as the $CompareAngle is not close to the 360/0 point.
Meaning, if $CompareAngle is 10 degrees for example the range should be 350-30 degrees.

But if I put that in the above line it will not work since it will become -10-30.
I could do `if($CompareAngle-20 <0){ do this if()} else{ other if }`
But is there a good method to compare angles/bearings like this without an bunch of if's, or is that not possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like something a modulo-operator would solve.

`if($bearing % 360 >= ($CompareAngle % 360)-20 % 360 && $bearing <= ($CompareAngle % 360) +20`

What modulo 360 (remainder after division by 360) basically does is, given a value `$bearing$`, subtract as many times 360 as possible as long as `$bearing > 0`.

Comment: I just tested the code and it seems to work. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You could calculate the actual difference.

```
$diff = abs($bearing - $CompareAngle);
```

Then check if it's in your acceptable range like this.

```
if ($diff <= 20 || $diff >= 340 )
```